# How to run capybara-webkit specs in bitbucket pipelines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit, bitbucket-pipelines

I've just integrated a project with bitbucket pipelines, but I'm receiving some errors with feature specs.
My first try, [as capybara-webkit mentioned](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit#ci), was to install `xvfb` and run `xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec`, so I left the script section in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file as follows:

```
image: ruby:2.2.5
# stuffs...
    script:
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
      - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential nodejs libpq-dev libmagickwand-dev imagemagick qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x xvfb
      - bundle install
      - cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
      - (cd client && npm install)
      - bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
      - xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec
```

But with this I started to receive `xvfb-run: error: xauth command not found`. Then I tried out the [headless gem](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless), I just left `bundle exec rspec` in the scripts section (without the call to `xvfb-run`) and added to my `spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    Headless.new(destroy_on_exit: false).start
  end
```

With this I've started to receive in the specs:

```
  1) Macros displays macro index
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:
     1.1) Failure/Error: visit macros_path
          EOFError:
            end of file reached
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read_nonblock'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:32:in `gets'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:299:in `check'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:211:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:19:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:50:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:233:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/features/macros_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     1.2) Failure/Error:
                  raise(Capybara::Webkit::CrashError, <<-MESSAGE.strip)
            The webkit_server process crashed!

              #{exception.message}

            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:

            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
                  MESSAGE
          Capybara::Webkit::CrashError:
            The webkit_server process crashed!
              Broken pipe
            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:
            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:215:in `rescue in command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:205:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:39:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:264:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:109:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `block in reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reverse_each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::EPIPE:
          #   Broken pipe
          #   /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:22:in `write'
  2) Messages when there are no messages displays a `no messages` message
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:
     2.1) Failure/Error: visit messages_path
          EOFError:
            end of file reached
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read_nonblock'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:32:in `gets'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:299:in `check'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:211:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:19:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:50:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:233:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/features/messages_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     2.2) Failure/Error:
                  raise(Capybara::Webkit::CrashError, <<-MESSAGE.strip)
            The webkit_server process crashed!

              #{exception.message}

            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:

            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
                  MESSAGE
          Capybara::Webkit::CrashError:
            The webkit_server process crashed!
              Broken pipe
            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:
            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:215:in `rescue in command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:205:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:39:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:264:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:109:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `block in reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reverse_each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara.rb:331:in `reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::EPIPE:
          #   Broken pipe
          #   /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:22:in `write'
```

As it is mentioned in the error, I followed the instructions to debug log in the [Reporting Crashes wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes) and the new displayed info was:

```
Finished "EnableLogging()" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)"
Started "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)"
Finished "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "SetTimeout(-1)"
Started "SetTimeout(-1)"
Finished "SetTimeout(-1)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:44341/macros)"
Started "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:44341/macros)"
Load started
"Visit(http://127.0.0.1:44341/macros)" started page load
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/macros"
Finished "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:44341/macros)" with response "Success()"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/application-d83f12f0b0ea0b43e79104a90e874634910929f3a471ffe1d17fce392956fc76.css"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/application-40a174b892afd166ed6429966cb6c56b09bb9aa5ed8a35b697855aca2ee9792a.js"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:44341/macros"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/logo128-8f969fe4ae654a8578aeb686f3c537290f2d2e4731cb15026c036d18a3456022.png"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/active_scaffold/indicator-07b202d8027099d3add8213095a203cecb4938acdebc80f755ef2251a1a5b880.gif"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/application-d83f12f0b0ea0b43e79104a90e874634910929f3a471ffe1d17fce392956fc76.css"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/active_scaffold/add-e1facc6f96a51e281f4fdfcdc0a648a6ff84cb2526523459343d8a4f6196a1da.png"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/active_scaffold/magnifier-475a6335fb52c21b5fa732518e89408f4277779bf5b015391358b047602b8aff.png"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/logo128-8f969fe4ae654a8578aeb686f3c537290f2d2e4731cb15026c036d18a3456022.png"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/active_scaffold/indicator-07b202d8027099d3add8213095a203cecb4938acdebc80f755ef2251a1a5b880.gif"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:44341/assets/application-40a174b892afd166ed6429966cb6c56b09bb9aa5ed8a35b697855aca2ee9792a.js"
Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration and more, see
  displays macro index (FAILED - 1)

Messages
  when there are no messages
Request to unknown URL: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.block_unknown_urls
  end
To allow just this URL:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css")
  end
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com")
  end
Request to unknown URL: https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.block_unknown_urls
  end
To allow just this URL:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css")
  end
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("code.ionicframework.com")
  end
Request to unknown URL: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.block_unknown_urls
  end
To allow just this URL:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic")
  end
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("fonts.googleapis.com")
  end
    displays a `no messages` message (FAILED - 2)
```

I'm planning to update the gems, maybe really is a bug, but I'm running out of ideas.
Any advise would be awesome.

**Update**

I've updated to `capybara-2.13.0` and `capybara-webkit-1.14.0`, but the error and debug messages are the same:

```
Finished "EnableLogging()" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)"
Started "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)"
Finished "SetUnknownUrlMode(block)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "SetTimeout(-1)"
Started "SetTimeout(-1)"
Finished "SetTimeout(-1)" with response "Success()"
Wrote response true ""
Received "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:34333/macros)"
Started "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:34333/macros)"
Load started
"Visit(http://127.0.0.1:34333/macros)" started page load
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/macros"
Finished "Visit(http://127.0.0.1:34333/macros)" with response "Success()"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/application-d83f12f0b0ea0b43e79104a90e874634910929f3a471ffe1d17fce392956fc76.css"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/application-40a174b892afd166ed6429966cb6c56b09bb9aa5ed8a35b697855aca2ee9792a.js"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:34333/macros"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/logo128-8f969fe4ae654a8578aeb686f3c537290f2d2e4731cb15026c036d18a3456022.png"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/active_scaffold/indicator-07b202d8027099d3add8213095a203cecb4938acdebc80f755ef2251a1a5b880.gif"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/application-d83f12f0b0ea0b43e79104a90e874634910929f3a471ffe1d17fce392956fc76.css"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/active_scaffold/add-e1facc6f96a51e281f4fdfcdc0a648a6ff84cb2526523459343d8a4f6196a1da.png"
Started request to "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/active_scaffold/magnifier-475a6335fb52c21b5fa732518e89408f4277779bf5b015391358b047602b8aff.png"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/logo128-8f969fe4ae654a8578aeb686f3c537290f2d2e4731cb15026c036d18a3456022.png"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/active_scaffold/indicator-07b202d8027099d3add8213095a203cecb4938acdebc80f755ef2251a1a5b880.gif"
Received 200 from "http://127.0.0.1:34333/assets/application-40a174b892afd166ed6429966cb6c56b09bb9aa5ed8a35b697855aca2ee9792a.js"
Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.* prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility, migration and more, see 
  displays macro index (FAILED - 1)
Messages
  when there are no messages
Request to unknown URL: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.block_unknown_urls
  end
To allow just this URL:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css")
  end
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com")
  end
Request to unknown URL: https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.block_unknown_urls
  end
To allow just this URL:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css")
  end
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("code.ionicframework.com")
  end
Request to unknown URL: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic
To block requests to unknown URLs:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.block_unknown_urls
  end
To allow just this URL:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic")
  end
To allow requests to URLs from this host:
  Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
    config.allow_url("fonts.googleapis.com")
  end
    displays a `no messages` message (FAILED - 2)
```

Error:

```
  1) Macros displays macro index
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:
     1.1) Failure/Error: visit macros_path
          EOFError:
            end of file reached
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read_nonblock'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:32:in `gets'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:315:in `check'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:221:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:20:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:50:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:254:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/features/macros_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     1.2) Failure/Error:
                  raise(Capybara::Webkit::CrashError, <<-MESSAGE.strip)
            The webkit_server process crashed!

              #{exception.message}

            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:

            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
                  MESSAGE
          Capybara::Webkit::CrashError:
            The webkit_server process crashed!
              Broken pipe
            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:
            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:227:in `rescue in command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:215:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:41:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:285:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:112:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara.rb:336:in `block in reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara.rb:336:in `reverse_each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara.rb:336:in `reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::EPIPE:
          #   Broken pipe
          #   /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:22:in `write'
  2) Messages when there are no messages displays a `no messages` message
     Got 0 failures and 2 other errors:
     2.1) Failure/Error: visit messages_path
          EOFError:
            end of file reached
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read_nonblock'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:41:in `read'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:32:in `gets'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:315:in `check'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:221:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:20:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:50:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:254:in `visit'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
          # ./spec/features/messages_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     2.2) Failure/Error:
                  raise(Capybara::Webkit::CrashError, <<-MESSAGE.strip)
            The webkit_server process crashed!

              #{exception.message}

            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:

            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
                  MESSAGE
          Capybara::Webkit::CrashError:
            The webkit_server process crashed!
              Broken pipe
            This is a bug in capybara-webkit. For help with this crash, please visit:
            https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Reporting-Crashes
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:227:in `rescue in command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:215:in `command'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:41:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:285:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:112:in `reset!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara.rb:336:in `block in reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara.rb:336:in `reverse_each'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara.rb:336:in `reset_sessions!'
          # /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-2.13.0/lib/capybara/rspec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
          # ------------------
          # --- Caused by: ---
          # Errno::EPIPE:
          #   Broken pipe
          #   /usr/local/bundle/gems/capybara-webkit-1.14.0/lib/capybara/webkit/connection.rb:22:in `write'
```

Comment: Have you tried allowing or blocking the urls suggested?  You also probably want to be using the production version of react in test mode, since it outputs its warnings as errors when not using the production version (or fix the warnings).

Comment: @ThomasWalpole not sure about the reason for the url warnings, I already have `Capybara::Webkit.configure(&:block_unknown_urls)` in `rails_helper.rb` but is displaying the message anyway. I'm going to try with the react production version and see what happens. In any case, I forgot to mention it, the specs are working for me locally, is just in bitbucket pipelines where those errors are thrown.